# Spark > why always one node inactive

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a YARN cluster with 5 nodes, 4 of which are worker nodes.

When I ran a Spark job I set "--num-executors 4", but even though when I checked from Spark application page, there are still only 3 active executors, meaning one node does not do anything, what is the reason?

Comment: Are you submitting to spark standalone or YARN?

Comment: Could you post a screenshot from your Spark UI?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the exact same problem. I believe the reason has something to do with YARN's memory management (which I won't pretend to understand!), but what solves it is to set `maximizeResourceAllocation` in the configurations file (as described here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ElasticMapReduce/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-configure.html)

At the resent Spark summit in Amsterdam, a number of people mentioned that even with this setting set, they occasionally observed that not all cores were utilized, so to make sure all cores are used I start my jobs with `--executor-cores X`, where X is the number of cores available on my executors.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you reply. I agree now that there must be some configuration problem with my cluster. But your mentioned maximizeResourceAllocation seems not to be in anywhere, I mean that I do not know where to configure it. the link you sent is about the setting in aws, but I do not use aws at all :<

Comment: Oh, I see... Maybe have a look at this post http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2015/03/how-to-tune-your-apache-spark-jobs-part-2/